# Why isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC returns false in this case?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm investigating how reference counting works in Swift. In the following snippet I instantiated a brand new Person object and check whether it's uniquely referenced. I believed it is uniquely referenced since it only retains on the "person" instance. However, isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC function returns false.

Can anyone explain why this is?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    var person = Person()

    // this will output not unique
    if isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC(&person) {
        println("unique")
    } else {
        println("not unique")
    }

    return true
}
```

Person class:

```
class Person: NSObject {

}
```

*EDIT* Interestingly when I don't make Person a subclass of NSObject then isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC will return true as expected. However, I still don't understand why subclassing NSObjct will make a difference here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us `Person` class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:FSs27isUniquelyReferencedNonObjCuRq_Ss9AnyObject_FRq_Sb) is documented as

```
/// Returns `true` iff `object` is a non-\ `@objc` class instance with
/// a single strong reference.
/// ...
/// * If `object` is an Objective-C class instance, returns `false`.
/// ...
```

Your `Person` class inherits from `NSObject`, therefore
`isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC(&person)` returns `false`.

Comment: @Vyacheslav: According to https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0125-remove-nonobjectivecbase.md, it was renamed to (or replaced by) [isKnownUniquelyReferenced](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2430721-isknownuniquelyreferenced). However, it does  *“... no longer promise to return false for `@objc` class instances”* so this answer may need an update.